# Is there a way to return a value from key value pairs based on the Key rather than index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to Javascript and I am stuck with this.

I have an array of objects

```
 const items = [
  {
    product: 'prodOne',
    quantity: 3,
    sending: 100, 
    receiving: 50
  }, 
  {
    product: 'prodTwo',
    quantity: 4,
    sending: 50, 
    receiving: 100
  }, 
  {
    product: 'prodThree',
    quantity: 8,
    sending: 100, 
    receiving: 100
  }
];
```

I am trying to change this array into an array of 2 key-value pairs, the new array would be something like this:

```
const itemsRed = [
  {
    product: 'prodOne',
    quantity: 3,
  }, 
  {
    product: 'prodTwo',
    quantity: 4,
  }, 
  {
    product: 'prodThree',
    quantity: 8,
  }
];
```

This is how I do it

```
const x = items.map(function (obj){
    var prod  = Object.values(obj)[0]
    var qty = Object.values(obj)[1]
    return {product: prod, quantity: qty}
})
```

The problem is that this depends on the index of the key-value pair [0] and if the positions are changed then it does not work. Is there a way to use the key instead of the index to get outcome.

```
const x = items.map(function (obj){
    var prod  = Object.values(obj)[0] //something like Object.values(obj['product']) which doesnt work
    var qty = Object.values(obj)[1]
    return {product: prod, quantity: qty}
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are really just asking how to access an object in the expected way. Perhaps start by reading up on the basics [MDN: Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), object destructuring as:

> You have to create an object with 2 properties `product` and `quantity`. So you can get it using `dot` notation or you can destructure it to get these 2 properties.

```
 const x = items.map(function(obj) {
     var prod = obj.product;    // USE DOT NOTATION TO GET product
     var qty = obj.quantity;    // USE DOT NOTATION TO GET quantity
     return {
         product: prod,
         quantity: qty
     }
 })
```

```js
const items = [{
    product: 'prodOne',
    quantity: 3,
    sending: 100,
    receiving: 50
  },
  {
    product: 'prodTwo',
    quantity: 4,
    sending: 50,
    receiving: 100
  },
  {
    product: 'prodThree',
    quantity: 8,
    sending: 100,
    receiving: 100
  }
];

const result = items.map(({ product, quantity }) => ({ product, quantity }));
console.log(result);
```

or

```js
const items = [{
    product: 'prodOne',
    quantity: 3,
    sending: 100,
    receiving: 50
  },
  {
    product: 'prodTwo',
    quantity: 4,
    sending: 50,
    receiving: 100
  },
  {
    product: 'prodThree',
    quantity: 8,
    sending: 100,
    receiving: 100
  }
];

const result = items.map((item) => ({
  product: item.product,
  quantity: item.quantity
}));
console.log(result);
```